# Issues with PySpark SQL using regexp_extract_all

Tags: sql, apache-spark

I'm trying to use a somewhat complex sql to extract data using spark. Here is the line
`GREATEST(COALESCE(TRY(CAST(element_at(regexp_extract_all(msg.lbb_diag_value, '"local_wwan0_t": {"rx": ([-0-9]*), "tx": ([-0-9]*), "rule": "LOCAL-WWAN0-INPUT-OUTPUT-CHAIN"},"wwan0_wlan0_t": {"rx": ([-0-9]*), "tx": ([-0-9]*), "rule": "WWAN0-WLAN0-FORWARD-CHAIN"}',1), 1) as BIGINT)), 0),0)  as wwan0_rx`

which throws the error
`"Undefined function: 'TRY'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.; line 5 pos 30"`

Here is the full sql for context

```
WITH FIRST as
        (SELECT SUM(wwan0_rx) AS wwan0_rx, SUM(wwan0_tx) AS wwan0_tx, SUM(wlan0_rx) AS wlan0_rx, SUM(wlan0_tx) AS wlan0_tx, identifier FROM
            (SELECT msg.identifier, msg.event_date AS msg_date,
            GREATEST(COALESCE(TRY(CAST(element_at(regexp_extract_all(msg.lbb_diag_value, '"local_wwan0_t": {"rx": ([-0-9]*), "tx": ([-0-9]*), "rule": "LOCAL-WWAN0-INPUT-OUTPUT-CHAIN"},"wwan0_wlan0_t": {"rx": ([-0-9]*), "tx": ([-0-9]*), "rule": "WWAN0-WLAN0-FORWARD-CHAIN"}',1), 1) as BIGINT)), 0),0)  as wwan0_rx,
            GREATEST(100, 0) as wwan0_tx,
            GREATEST(100, 0) as wlan0_rx,
            GREATEST(100, 0) as wlan0_tx
            FROM eld_non_vehicle_messages AS msg
            WHERE msg.type IN ('lbb_diag')
                AND msg.lbb_diag_type IN ('data-usage')
                AND msg.event_date >= '2020-10-15'
                AND msg.event_date <= '2020-10-16'
                AND msg.sw_pkg_version >= 70024)
        GROUP BY identifier
        ORDER BY identifier desc
        LIMIT 50
        )
```

I tried using a bunch of ways to escape the double quotes but doesnt seem to work. I plan on replacing the subsequent GREATEST(100, 0) as wwan0_tx lines to this format as well

Comment: Is the "snowflake" tag correct? The question doesn't seem to be related

Comment: Does the query work when you run it directly in the source database (snowflake?) Maybe you mean `TRY_CAST(`, not `TRY(CAST(`?

Comment: There is no try cast in Spark SQL. A normal cast will do. Also there is no regexp_extract_all in Spark SQL.

Comment: -> my apologies - since I'm using snowflake to store data thought of mentioning it - removed it now
-> the problem here is what I'm reading from s3 and storing in snowflake - hence I cannot run it on the snowflake to see if it works or not :(
-> I removed try - then it got stuck with the same error but now with regexp_extract_all :- I referenced this pr saying that it should be merged now https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/27507 so trying it out